# How to get IP address in PHP?

Tags: php

I am creating a project. Now I want the IP address of the guest who are unauthorized person.

Comment: Yes https://www.google.com/search?q=php+get+ip+address

Comment: try this: $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']. Check this: http://in3.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get Client IP address in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003145/how-to-get-client-ip-address-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<?php $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

try this one   `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`
you can also check here for more info [How to get the client IP address in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003145/how-to-get-client-ip-address-in-php)