# Get client IP address Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have tried multiple options to get client IP address including pinging third-party server, but i don't think its a good idea since my office's network is very complicated.

I have a requirement where I need to check user's IP address so that I know if the user is using internet or intranet.

Someone told me to get headers and use "X-FORWARDED_FOR" but i'm clueless about it because i'm a newbie frontend developer.

Can someone help me? thank you

Comment: you mean internet or intranet?

Comment: both. i need to check if the user is using internet or intranet by checking their first subnet IP

Comment: You get the IP address in server. E.g. if you're using .NET and a Controller check this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28664686/how-do-i-get-client-ip-address-in-asp-net-core), if you're using PHP check [this another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21547733/how-to-get-ip-address-in-php) else ...

Answer (score 1):

If it's not against your company's policy you can just make a request to `http://icanhazip.com/`

```
@Injectable({…})
export class IpService {

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

   getIp(): Observable<string> {
     return this.httpClient.get('http://icanhazip.com/', {responseType: 'text'})
   }

}
```

**Note** this will only give you your public IP address. Unless you have some internal server service running in the local network, from the browser, you're unable to know subnets and LAN IP addresses.

Comment: it worked but i guess i need to ask my supervisor first if its against the company's policy or not. thank youu!